# How to show last value from data ( array passed to charts ) at axis line (x-axis)?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, echarts

In below picture,

The date displayed at end of axis line (x-axis) is diff from date displayed at end of data zoom.

Required,

The date should be same, at axis line & data zoom, When no zoom is applied.
The date should be the last value in data that is passed to charts by settings.

Screenshot is taken from official site of echarts.

https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=area-rainfall 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the chart *does* show data up to `2009/10/18`, but since the xAxis ticks aren't equally spaced, there's a small area at the chart's end

Look what happens when I hover over the chart's right end. It does show you `2009/10/18`.

[image]

Because the axis ticks are alligned from the left, and the chart's axis is dynamic (because of the custom zoom range), it may not always fit perfectly.

---

You can, however, play a little with the ticks and labels.

For example, when you have 100 datapoints, you can change the tick interval and label from `auto` to, let's say, `10` (or another whole number divisible by the number of datapoints).

```
xAxis: [
    {
        axisTick: {
            interval: 10
        },
        axisLabel: {
            interval: 10
        },
    }
]
```